# Quotient rule for multivariable functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$\newcommand{\mbf}{\mathbf}$
Let $f,g:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ be differentiable at $a$.

$Df(a)$ is the unique linear transformation $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb  R$ such that
$$\lim_{\mbf h\to\mbf 0}\frac{|f(\mbf a+\mbf h)-\mbf f(\mbf a)-Df(\mbf a)(\mbf h)|}{|\mbf h|}=0.$$

I want to show that if $g(a)\neq 0$, then $D(f/g)(a)=\dfrac{g(a)Df(a)-f(a)Dg(a)}{[g(a)]^2}$.

I've shown that $D(f\cdot g)(a)=g(a)Df(a)+f(a)Dg(a)$.

Let $h:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $h(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}$. Then
$$D(f/g)(a)=D(f\cdot h)(a)=h(a)Df(a)+f(a)Dh(a).$$

Since $h=q\circ g$ where $q:\mathbb R-\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ is defined by $q(x)=1/x$,
$$Dh(a)=D(q\circ g)(a)=Dq(g(a))\circ Dg(a)=D\frac1{g(a)}\circ Dg(a)$$

How can I simplify $D\frac 1{g(x)}$ to prove this?

Comment: Hint:  $0=D(g\cdot (1/g)).$

Comment: Then $1/g(a) Dg(a)=-g(a) D(1/g(a))$. How should I use this?

Comment: You can divide both sides by $-g(a)$ to compute $D(1/g(a))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun: $Dq(g(a))$ is the derivative of $q : \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R$ at the point $g(a) \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, which can be more helpful writing it as $(Dq)(g(a))$, viewing $Dq$ as a map from $\mathbb R$ to the space of all linear transformations $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. So, the symbol $D \frac{1}{g(a)}$ doesn't make sense.

Anyway, it is well known that $q'(y) = -y^{-2}$ for any $y \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, which means that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{q(y+h)-q(y)+y^{-2}h}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \bigg( \frac{q(y+h)-q(y)}{h} + y^{-2} \bigg) = -y^{-2}+y^{-2} = 0$$
and so
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|q(y+h)-q(y)+y^{-2}h|}{|h|} = 0.$$
Therefore $Dq(y) : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is the map that sends $h$ to $-y^{-2}h$, and in particular, $Dq(g(a))$ is the map that sends $h$ to $-g(a)^{-2}h$, that is, $Dq(g(a))$ is $-g(a)^{-2}$ times the identity map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to show that $D\frac{1}{g(a)}=-\frac{Dg(a)}{g^2(a)}$ and for this is necessary and sufficient that

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|1/g(a+h)- 1/g(a)+D(g(a))(h)/g^2(a)|}{|h|}=0.$$

Indeed, note that

$$\frac{|1/g(a+h)- 1/g(a)+D(g(a))(h)/g^2(a)|}{|h|}=\frac{|g^2(a)-g(a)g(a+h)+g(a+h)Dg(a)(h)|}{|g^2(a)g(a+h)h|}\leq\frac{|g^2(a)-g(a)g(a+h)+g(a)Dg(a)(h)|}{|g^2(a)g(a+h)h|}+\frac{|g(a+h)Dg(a)(h)-g(a)Dg(a)(h)}{|g^2(a)g(a+h)h|}=\frac{|g(a+h)-g(a)-Dg(a)(h)|}{|g(a)g(a+h)||h|}+\frac{|(g(a+h)-g(a))Dg(a)(h/|h|)}{|g^2(a)g(a+h)|},$$

where making $h\to0$ the first summand $\to0$ by the differentiability of $g$ and the second summand $\to0$ because it is the product of a function wich converges to $0$ and a bounded function.